# Batch file set command issue

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Have created a batch script and found that the values are not getting set when trying to read from **for** loop.

```
sqlplus @D:\Batch_job\Sql\COUNT.sql>D:\Batch_job\COUNT.txt

FIND /C /I "ORA-" D:\Batch_job\COUNT.txt >D:\Batch_job\ERR.txt

FOR /F "tokens=3" %%B IN (D:\Batch_job\ERR.txt) DO SET COUNT_ERROR=%%B

ECHO %COUNT_ERROR%
```

The above echo is not returning any value. I tried using `enabledelayedexpansion`, too. But that is also not working. When I tried to create some test script and execute just this much chunk than it is giving me result. But when called from the whole script the result is always same NULL.

Comment: We can't help without seeing the contents of the file you are parsing.

Comment: Also, is this the ENTIRE script? The above will not work if it is part of another FOR loop or IF construct.

Comment: The command __FOR__ as used here processes each line of file __ERR.txt__. For each line the third string after 1 or more spaces/tabs is assigned to environment variable `COUNT_ERROR`. So if the last line of the file does not contain `string1 string2 string3`, i.e. at least 3 strings with spaces/tabs between, the result is `SET COUNT_ERROR=` which results in deletion of the environment variable. Use command `echo on` above line with command __FOR__ and run the batch file from within a console window and you can see what command line interpreter does on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Maybe `sqlplus` generates `UNICODE` output? Compare output from `FOR /F "tokens=*" %%B IN (D:\Batch_job\COUNT.txt) DO @echo "%%B"` and `FOR /F "tokens=*" %%B IN ('type D:\Batch_job\COUNT.txt') DO @echo "%%B"` (and let us know, please)